# Issue with more than one LUIS Dialog and its entities

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service

I'm try to create a bot with multiple Luis intents, it means multiple dialogs naturally. I've installed the default CoreBot template (Downloaded from Azure). After setting intents and entities;
created second dialog which name is 'WeatherDialog', 
created "WeatherDetails" which consists of getter and setter for my LUIS weather entities,
implemented some of code for accessing to entities' results to partial class which is already in the project for BookingDialog.

Then in the MainDialog, I tried to AddDialog.

MainDialog:

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Recognizers.Text.DataTypes.TimexExpression;
using CoreBot;

namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Dialogs
{
    public class MainDialog : ComponentDialog
    {
        private readonly FlightBookingRecognizer _luisRecognizer;
        protected readonly ILogger Logger;

        // Dependency injection uses this constructor to instantiate MainDialog
        public MainDialog(FlightBookingRecognizer luisRecognizer, BookingDialog bookingDialog, CoreBot.Dialogs.WeatherDialog weatherDialog, ILogger<MainDialog> logger)
            : base(nameof(MainDialog))
        {
            _luisRecognizer = luisRecognizer;
            Logger = logger;

            AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));
            AddDialog(bookingDialog);
            AddDialog(weatherDialog);
            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                IntroStepAsync,
                ActStepAsync,
                FinalStepAsync,
            }));

            // The initial child Dialog to run.
            InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
        }



        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> IntroStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (!_luisRecognizer.IsConfigured)
            {
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(
                    MessageFactory.Text("NOTE: LUIS is not configured. To enable all capabilities, add 'LuisAppId', 'LuisAPIKey' and 'LuisAPIHostName' to the appsettings.json file.", inputHint: InputHints.IgnoringInput), cancellationToken);

                return await stepContext.NextAsync(null, cancellationToken);
            }

            // Use the text provided in FinalStepAsync or the default if it is the first time.
            var messageText = stepContext.Options?.ToString() ?? "How can I help you?";
            var promptMessage = MessageFactory.Text(messageText, messageText, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = promptMessage }, cancellationToken);
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ActStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (!_luisRecognizer.IsConfigured)
            {
                // LUIS is not configured, we just run the BookingDialog path with an empty BookingDetailsInstance.
                return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(BookingDialog), new BookingDetails(), cancellationToken);
            }

            // Call LUIS and gather any potential booking details. (Note the TurnContext has the response to the prompt.)
            var luisResult = await _luisRecognizer.RecognizeAsync<CoreBot.WeatherModel>(stepContext.Context, cancellationToken);
            switch (luisResult.TopIntent().intent)
            {
                case CoreBot.WeatherModel.Intent.BookFlight:
                    //await ShowWarningForUnsupportedCities(stepContext.Context, luisResult, cancellationToken);
                    Console.WriteLine("This is bookflight");
                    // Initialize BookingDetails with any entities we may have found in the response.
                    var bookingDetails = new BookingDetails()
                    {
                        // Get destination and origin from the composite entities arrays.
                        Destination = luisResult.ToEntities.Airport,
                        Origin = luisResult.FromEntities.Airport,
                        TravelDate = luisResult.TravelDate,
                    };

                    // Run the BookingDialog giving it whatever details we have from the LUIS call, it will fill out the remainder.
                    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(BookingDialog), bookingDetails, cancellationToken);

                case CoreBot.WeatherModel.Intent.GetWeather:
                    Console.WriteLine("This is getweather");
                    var weatherDetails = new CoreBot.WeatherDetails()
                    {
                        Location = luisResult.Location,
                        TravelDate = luisResult.TravelDate,
                    };
                    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(CoreBot.Dialogs.WeatherDialog), weatherDetails, cancellationToken);

                default:
                    // Catch all for unhandled intents
                    var didntUnderstandMessageText = $"Sorry, I didn't get that. Please try asking in a different way (intent was {luisResult.TopIntent().intent})";
                    var didntUnderstandMessage = MessageFactory.Text(didntUnderstandMessageText, didntUnderstandMessageText, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
                    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(didntUnderstandMessage, cancellationToken);
                    break;
            }

            return await stepContext.NextAsync(null, cancellationToken);
        }

        // Shows a warning if the requested From or To cities are recognized as entities but they are not in the Airport entity list.
        // In some cases LUIS will recognize the From and To composite entities as a valid cities but the From and To Airport values
        // will be empty if those entity values can't be mapped to a canonical item in the Airport.
        private static async Task ShowWarningForUnsupportedCities(ITurnContext context, FlightBooking luisResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var unsupportedCities = new List<string>();

            var fromEntities = luisResult.FromEntities;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromEntities.From) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromEntities.Airport))
            {
                unsupportedCities.Add(fromEntities.From);
            }

            var toEntities = luisResult.ToEntities;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(toEntities.To) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(toEntities.Airport))
            {
                unsupportedCities.Add(toEntities.To);
            }

            if (unsupportedCities.Any())
            {
                var messageText = $"Sorry but the following airports are not supported: {string.Join(',', unsupportedCities)}";
                var message = MessageFactory.Text(messageText, messageText, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
                await context.SendActivityAsync(message, cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> FinalStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // If the child dialog ("BookingDialog") was cancelled, the user failed to confirm or if the intent wasn't BookFlight
            // the Result here will be null.
            if (stepContext.Result is BookingDetails result)
            {
                // Now we have all the booking details call the booking service.

                // If the call to the booking service was successful tell the user.

                var timeProperty = new TimexProperty(result.TravelDate);
                var travelDateMsg = timeProperty.ToNaturalLanguage(DateTime.Now);
                var messageText = $"I have you booked to {result.Destination} from {result.Origin} on {travelDateMsg}";
                var message = MessageFactory.Text(messageText, messageText, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(message, cancellationToken);
            }
            else if (stepContext.Result is CoreBot.WeatherDetails sonuc)
            {
                var timeProperty = new TimexProperty(sonuc.TravelDate);
                var weatherDateMsg = timeProperty.ToNaturalLanguage(DateTime.Now);
                var messageText = $"Thats your weather result for {weatherDateMsg} at {sonuc.Location}: 00 F";
                var message = MessageFactory.Text(messageText, messageText, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(message, cancellationToken);
            }

            // Restart the main dialog with a different message the second time around
            var promptMessage = "What else can I do for you?";
            return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(InitialDialogId, promptMessage, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

And also my WeatherDialog:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;
using Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Recognizers.Text.DataTypes.TimexExpression;

namespace CoreBot.Dialogs
{
    public class WeatherDialog : CancelAndHelpDialog
    {
        private const string DestinationStepMsgText = "Type the location.";


        public WeatherDialog()
            : base(nameof(WeatherDialog))
        {
            AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));
            AddDialog(new ConfirmPrompt(nameof(ConfirmPrompt)));
            AddDialog(new DateResolverDialog());
            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                LocationStepAsync,
                TravelDateStepAsync,
                ConfirmStepAsync,
                FinalStepAsync,
            }));

            // The initial child Dialog to run.
            InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> LocationStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var weatherDetails = (WeatherDetails)stepContext.Options;

            if (weatherDetails.Location == null)
            {
                var promptMessage = MessageFactory.Text(DestinationStepMsgText, DestinationStepMsgText, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
                return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = promptMessage }, cancellationToken);
            }

            return await stepContext.NextAsync(weatherDetails.Location, cancellationToken);
        }


        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> TravelDateStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var weatherDetails = (WeatherDetails)stepContext.Options;

            weatherDetails.Location = (string)stepContext.Result;

            if (weatherDetails.TravelDate == null || IsAmbiguous(weatherDetails.TravelDate))
            {
                return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(DateResolverDialog), weatherDetails.TravelDate, cancellationToken);
            }

            return await stepContext.NextAsync(weatherDetails.TravelDate, cancellationToken);
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ConfirmStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var weatherDetails = (WeatherDetails)stepContext.Options;

            weatherDetails.TravelDate = (string)stepContext.Result;

            var messageText = $"You want to know weather status at {weatherDetails.Location} for {weatherDetails.TravelDate}. Is this correct?";
            var promptMessage = MessageFactory.Text(messageText, messageText, InputHints.ExpectingInput);

            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ConfirmPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = promptMessage }, cancellationToken);
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> FinalStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if ((bool)stepContext.Result)
            {
                var weatherDetails = (WeatherDetails)stepContext.Options;

                return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(weatherDetails, cancellationToken);
            }

            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken);
        }

        private static bool IsAmbiguous(string timex)
        {
            var timexProperty = new TimexProperty(timex);
            return !timexProperty.Types.Contains(Constants.TimexTypes.Definite);
        }
    }
}
```

After I build the code from Visual Studio then start conversation from Bot Framework Emulator. 
And the following dialog goes like this:

- How is the weather today?
  +The bot encounted an error or bug. -> Failed
  +To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code.
- How is the weather today at Los Angeles?
- -> Successful
- How is the weather at Los Angeles?
  +The bot encounted an error or bug. -> Failed
  +To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code.
- book me flight
- -> Successful
- How is the weather tomorrow at Tokyo?
- -> Successful ............

Briefly, when running the bookingDialog with missing parameters (entities), bot asks the missing parameter. However, when I run the weatherDialog with missing parameters conversation overs with error.

When I look the LUIS trace in Bot Framework Emulator, intent and entity recognized successfully.

As you can see, bookingDialog works like a charm but my dialog doesn't work. Can you please help me? What am I missing?

Comment: What exception are you getting in Visual studio? It helps to get the exception message and stack trace to see which line in your code the error originates from. If VS is not breaking then enable all exceptions. To do this, start debugging, then at the bottom click "Exception settings". Make sure all exception categories are checked (if it's a box then only partially checked, click again to make it a tick).

Make the error appear again to see what exception happens. (Note sometimes there's 'routine' exceptions that don't break the program. just F5 to continue through them)

Comment: The `please fix the bot source code` message comes from the CoreBot demo class `AdapterWithErrorHandler`. You should set a break point in the `OnTurnError` handler. Also, like @waleed suggested, it sounds like you might have debugger exceptions turned off (the default).